# Tag for questions like "What _____ are available?"?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are a lot of questions like [What native games are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6586/what-native-games-are-available) and [What docks are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8865/what-docks-are-available). Do you think we should make a tag for them? The first thing that comes to mind is `available-software`, but I don't think this is very descriptive. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

It is easy for "list" questions to fail the [SE subjective guidelines](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/); before worrying about tags, figure out if we want mindless lists all.  Usually these questions would be much better if made more specific; e.g. "My specific needs are X, Y, and Z. I've already tried A, and it didn't work for me because of B.  What tools can I use to do C?"

[Meta-tagging is explicitly discouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/), and that means there shouldn't be a tag for this "type" of question.  Tag the content of the question.  E.g. if it's asking about RSS feeds, tag [feeds]; if it's about capturing video, [video]; editing music, [music-editor]; and so forth.

Just because every question has 5 tags doesn't mean we have to fill them up.

Comment: For example, one user [posted 12(!)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/594/list-of-blogs-to-learn-more-about-ubuntu) answers that say nothing except a name and a blog link.  Now I know they were trying to help, but since the answers weren't even community wiki, it's an abuse of the rep system and definitely not something that helps Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea, but would prefer something a tag like `software-choices` or perhaps `software-options`.

Answer (score 0):

I've just been lumping them under `application`